# Heroku throws npm ERR! Missing script: "start" at me

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy simple app on Heroku but it seems to be crashing with this errors.

I have included

```
    "start": "node app.js",
```

And web: node app.js in Procfile but it doesn't seem to help at all, I just get more errors.

Any idea what that might be?

Error log:

[image]

Comment: "I have included" — where, exactly, did you include that? Provide more context.

Comment: Inside package.json

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
  },

Comment: `npm run start` perhaps?

Comment: For now I started getting "Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app."  when trying to push commit. Once I sort this out I'll try this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy you are a legend mate. It worked. At least I think it was this but it works now. Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: @Ramboski it's nice to have my legendary status recognised once in a while :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your package.json folder, under "scripts", you have to add the code you listed. It should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "start": "node app.js"  // your code
},
```

Comment: I did that under scripts but aboe the "test" line. Changed it just now so it's underneath it but now it doesn't even let me push the master.

Comment: It's because you've already pushed the master and probably switched to another branch.

Comment: 1. git add .
2. git commit -m “xyz about commit”
3. git push heroku master

Comment: At first it was this, then I've realised what am I doing and it still didn't work. I was flipping the lines in package.json and forgot to delete comma. It works now! Thank you.

Comment: Great news! Do you mind marking the answer as complete?